Is the x-capacitor essential in the circuit below?

hi
I hear a buzzing noise from c1 and L1 in this circuit
C1 used a film capacitor, not an X capacitor
(Film capacitors were used instead of x capacitors because of internal space problems.)
I thought the noise like hum was usually an inductor or line filter problem.
The important thing is to remove the c1, and the buzzing noise disappears.
Why is that?
++ fisrt of all voltage between j1 to j2(Line to Neutral) is AC220V
++ C2 is 15uF/400V, not 4.7uF

You're saying that you have a non-x-rated capacitor between live and neutral? Not sure if thats safe (or legal), even with the fuse

yeah. 104k/275v cap is film capacitor, not X-capacitor
I think they put it in place of a varistor, but I'm not sure

As my old boss used to say: "there is always time to do the right thing, either before or after it's 'too late'".

I hear a buzzing noise is it buzz or hum (lower frequency)?

it's an audiable buzz

Capacitors can vibrate due to electrostriction, a change in material dimensions (strain) in response to polarization (applied voltage).  This is a square-law phenomenon, so you get a 100Hz hum from a 50Hz mains supply.  It might have a sharp buzzing sound due to loose materials in the capacitor construction.
C1 is more likely, but C2 is still a contender, depending on its properties.  It's bigger, so even though the ripple voltage might be smaller, it may be a better transducer.  It would also have a peaky (buzzy) waveform.
It's also possible the inductor is buzzing, not due to core behavior (there is the analogous magnetostriction) because current is compensated (if it's wired properly, at least), but perhaps due to peak currents causing the wires to shift.  This should be a small effect outside of quite large currents (100s A peak?), even for fine wires, so I think it's unlikely.

L1 and C1 are creating a tank which has a resonance in the audible range and some  noise (ripple) exists at or near this resonant frequency.
f_resonance = 1/[2 * pi * sqrt(LC)] = 5032 Hz
This causes mechanical vibration of the component which you can hear.  If the values of L and C are chosen such that the resonance is not in the audible spectrum, the noise will disappear.
Alternatively if you add filtering on the rectified output, this can have a similar effect.

This is an incorrect calculation for several reasons: C1's voltage is defined by J1/J2; L1 is a CMC with LL probably 100uH; and D1 is only a near-short (AC) during peaks charging C2.
